# How to make Windows Phone 8 App backwards compatible?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1, backwards-compatibility

I have a Windows 8.1 Pro machine with Visual Studio 2012 and 2013.

I have installed the Windows Phone 8 SDK. This is supposed to also support Windows Phone 7.

I can create projects which target the Windows Phone 8 version.

However I am unable to find a way to enable targeting Windows Phone 7.

I tried this: http://www.nitrix-reloaded.com/2012/09/10/how-toinstall-windows-phone-7-1-sdk-in-windows-8/ but the last step failed and I did not get any option to create a new project targeting Windows Phone 7.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2013 can only target 8.0. 2012 can target both. If you can't see the option to target 7.1 try to install all VS updates.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I did not know that VS 2013 does not target WP7. I have VS2012 with update 4 and I still can't see the option to target WP7.

Answer (score 0):

If you develop an app that targets Windows Phone 7, it can be executed on both WP 7 and WP 8 If your application only targets Windows Phone 8, you will not be able to use it on Windows Phone 7 devices.

If you want an app for both platforms you have to install Windows Phone 7 SDK in order to develop applications for that OS. Also you can install Windows Phone 7 SDK Update for 7.8 version.

If you want to share code between different versions, you can use PCL libraries.